# Add Controls to Show Morris Chart

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, raphael, morris.js

I have 3 buttons: Day, Week, and Month. How to do when I click eg: Day button, the morris chart will show the results with days on x-axis; when I click eg: Week button, the morris chart will show the results with weeks on x-axis. Is this doable? FYI: I'm using Laravel 4 for backend.

//controller.php

```
$day= U::select('u.price', DB::raw('DATE(u.solddate) as day'))
        ->orderBy('u.solddate','DESC')
        ->get();
```

//js

```
$("#day").click(function(){
    $("svg, .morris-hover.morris-default-style").remove();
    var line = new Morris.Line({
        element: 'line-chart',
        resize: true,
        data: {{$day}},
        xkey: 'day',
        ykeys: ['price'],
        labels: ['Price'],
        lineColors: ['#3c8dbc'],
        hideHover: 'auto'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you will be able to achieve what you want.

Let's assume all your data are stored in `$day`, `$week` and `$month`.

So for this given HTML:

```
<div id="line-chart" style="height: 300px;"></div>
<hr/>
<button data-type="day">Day</button> |
<button data-type="week">Week</button> |
<button data-type="month">Month</button>
```

You therefore need to do:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#line-chart').empty();
        var type = $(this).data('type')

        , month = {{ $month}}

        , week = {{ $week }}

        , day = {{ $day }}

        , data = {
            month: month,
            week: week,
            day: day
            }

        , line = new Morris.Line({
            element: 'line-chart',
            resize: true,
            data: data[type],
            xkey: 'y',
            ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
            labels: ['Price', 'Test'],
            lineColors: ['#3c8dbc', '#3c8dbc'],
            hideHover: 'auto'
        })
        ;

    });

});
```

See this [working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2cdkbg6h/2/)

Comment: @hahahaha: No worries. Happy coding!